# Excel Date Issue

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2003 VBA code, I copied a date from a form into a cell, which I then formatted as vbLongDate. This puts in a date like "Wednesday, August 13, 2014". I am struggling with getting the date components back out, though. I am trying this

```
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = Date(Range("A1").Value)
```

From there, I want to pull out the year, month and day values from myDate, but this isn't working. I tried a few variations, but they are all bombing out.

Thanks!

Comment: The cell is already in "General" format. I just tried `myDate = Range("A1").Value` and that breaks, too.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't read it properly. `Date(x)` is not a conversion function - there is only a parameterless method `Date()`, which returns current system date. Try `CDate(x)` for date conversions. However, CDate can't handle a string in the format you specify - you will have to extract the components needed (or as teylyn says, change your original procedure to output the date as an actual date datatype).

Comment: CDate() broke on a "Type Mismatch"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the FormatDateTime() function with vbLongDate. That returns text. Consider formatting the cell with a date format instead and retain its date properties.

```
Sub test()
Dim myDate As Date
' this will return text
Range("A1") = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongDate)
' A2 will remain a date
Range("A2") = Date
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"

myDate = Range("A2").Value
Debug.Print Month(myDate) ' no error
End Sub
```

**Edit:** Depending on the date format used, the appearance of the date will adjust to the regional settings.

```
' this date format will adjust to the regional settings
' my regional settings are DMY and I see "Thursday, 14 August 2014"
' even though the format shows the mmmm before the dd
    myRange1.NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"

' this date format will always be like displayed below
    myRange2.NumberFormat = "dddd, d mmmm yyyy;@"
```

You could set different formats to different cells, depending on whether they need to adjust or not.

Comment: I went through this, too. The explanation is a bit long, give me a minute to type it in...

Comment: I am creating a workbook that may be used by Americans on US-configured PCs, but they need to display dates in non-US formats. When they are using non-US versions of my spreadsheet, I'd like the dates to come up in those formats - like "dd/mm/yyyy". But there are also versions of the spreadsheet that should display in US format.

Comment: Forget Calendar controls, they never seem to appear on anyone else's PC. I split the day, month and year fields into separate textboxes because a single box was not working.

Comment: I do have a field that can tell me which date format I' working with.

Comment: Please edit the question with all that information. Comments are not for conversational discussions. Excel has date formats that adjust to regional settings. These are marked with an asterisk in the format dialog. All other formats are absolute and will not change with regional settings.